# browser caching .htaccesss is not working

Tags: html, .htaccess, caching, browser-cache, http-caching

My code for Leverage browser caching doesn't seem to work i have written the following in the .htaccess but when i ran PageSpeed insights i get the Leverage Browser:

Can somebody kindly advice on what i am doing wrong?

```
  ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType images/dots.gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType images/homepage/1.5mw_installed.jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType images/homepage/350kw_optimizers.jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ......
    ExpiresByType stylesheets/responsive.css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType stylesheets/teal.css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType stylesheets/style.css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType stylesheets/websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.woff "access plus 1 month"
    </IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#==== CACHE FILES FOR 1 WEEK ====
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

You can change which files you want to cache in the list (remove or add).
Change the `ExpiresDefault` to change how long files are cached for.

This code is tested and works. Google Page Speed recognises it.